# Automatically create iterator from class that implements operator[]

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class that implements `operator[]`, e.g.:

```
class Array {
public:
  Array(size_t s) : data(new int[s]) {}
  ~Array() { delete[] data; }
  int& operator[](size_t index) {
    return data[index];
  }
private:
  int* data;
};
```

Is there a way to create a random access iterator from the class without having to manually create the iterator class and all its methods? I could manually define the class as follows:

```
class ArrayIterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, int> {
  public:
    ArrayIterator(Array& a) : arr(a), index(0) {}
    reference operator[](difference_type i) {
      return arr[index + i];
    }
    ArrayIterator& operator+=(difference_type i) {
      index += i;
      return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const ArrayIterator& rhs) {
      return &arr == &rhs.arr && index == rhs.index;
    }

  // More methods here...

  private:
    Array& arr;
    difference_type index;
};
```

But doing so is time consuming since there are so many methods to implement, and each iterator for a class with operator[] would have the exact same logic. It seems it would be possible for the compiler to do this automatically, so is there a way to avoid implementing the entire iterator?

Comment: *But doing so is time consuming since there are so many methods to implement, and each iterator for a class with operator[] would have the exact same logic.* That description fits well for a class template.

Comment: You may not really need an iterator. stl algorithms works fine with raw pointers too.

Comment: Unless your `operator[]` returns some kind of Optional, it's not enough to have an `operator[]`; you'd need to have some sort of `size()` as well

Comment: I could use a class template, but ideally I would avoid implementing it even once :).

Comment: @balki, my actual class with `operator[]` doesn't use pointers, so I have to use an iterator that calls `operator[]`.
@Justin, I don't think iterators need to know the size, as long as the user of the iterator knows the size and makes sure to not go out of bounds.

Comment: @balki a raw pointer **is** a `RandomAccessIterator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a random access iterator from the class without having to manually create the iterator class and all its methods?

The simplest way to create a random-access iterator is to just use a raw pointer, which satisfies all of the requirements of the [`RandomAccessIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) concept (the STL even provides a default template specialization of [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) for raw pointers), eg:

```
class Array {
public:
    Array(size_t s) : data(new int[s]), dataSize(s) {}
    ~Array() { delete[] data; }

    int& operator[](size_t index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    size_t size() const { return dataSize; } 
    int* begin() { return data; }
    int* end() { return data+dataSize; }
    const int* cbegin() const { return data; }
    const int* cend() const { return data+dataSize; }

private:
    int* data;
    size_t dataSize;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Implementing the random access operator by using `operator[]` may work, but it can be very inefficient and that's why compilers dont do that automatically. Just imagine adding `operator[]` to a class like `std::list`, where "going to element i" may take up to i steps. Incrementing an iterator based on `operator[]` would then have complexity O(n), where n is the size of the list. However, users of random access iterators, expect a certain efficiency, typically O(1).

Comment: `std::list` **doesn't have** an `operator[]` for exactly this reason. It can be assumed that if a class has an `operator[](ptr_diff_t)` then it is reasonable to call it.